# Google Realtime Multiplayer trouble. Automatch with 4 players doesn't work

Tags: android, google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

I have a strange problem. I am developing a game with the multiplayer api from google play  services. I want to create rooms with 4 random players. I have this code:

**Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(3, 3, 0);**

When i have 2 min and 2 max opponents, then it works perfectly and show the message "prepare to play" in my devices.
But with 3 opponents, it doesnt work. Every player keeps waiting.

What can it be? It's horrible to have a problem so as soon.

Comment: I think you have to do like that : (4,4,0)

Comment: I dont think so. (4,4,0) is for 4 opponents, and 5 players total. And if it doesnt work with 3 opponents, is posible that it doesnt work with 4 too.

Comment: IT was a problem with the google acounts :(  .